# How to run CHKDSK on Windows XP when XP won't start

Tags: windows, windows-xp, chkdsk

My Gateway running Windows XP attempts to start Windows, but then restarts and won't ever finish loading Windows.

I'd like to run CHKDSK to see if its a bad sector. However, since it can't load Windows, how do I get to the command-prompt to run CHKDSK?

I've searched here and on the internet, and haven't really seen any solid answers.

Comment: With an XP disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try booting to a [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) livecd disk and running it that way.  Be sure to include the checkdisk [plugin](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/plugins/)

Answer (score 3):

As @Rob suggested, you can also boot off of the Windows XP CD. When you boot up, it firsts asks you to `Press a key to boot the CD`, so do so. As it's loading, instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to load setup, press <kbd>R</kbd> to load the recovery console. From there, choose the Windows installation, type the Administrator password, then run your `CHKDSK C: /f /p`.